# Run a timer infinitely until button pressed?

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

How can I add timed functionality that doesn't end unless the button is clicked again?
This runs a thread okay but it won't restart unless I go to another tab in the app and go back to it.

```
 metroStartBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            metronomeOn = !metronomeOn;

            if(metronomeOn)
            {
                final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        while(!toExit){
                            // Your code
                            try {
                                playSound(getContext(), 1);
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                    t.start();

            }

            else
            {
                toExit = true;
            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after the first run , toExit is true therefore your while loop will not execute after that

```
metroStartBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            metronomeOn = !metronomeOn;

            if(metronomeOn)
            {
                final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        while(metronomeOn){
                            // Your code
                            try {
                                playSound(getContext(), 1);
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                t.start();

            }
        }

    });
```